# Resolve failing for %any in strongswan ipsec

Tags: ipsec, strongswan

I was configuring ipsec between 2 linux boxes.
Since ip of our product can be different when connected to different spaces. I used **%any for right**.
Since then, I am not able to **up** my ipsec transport mode connection. But when i give specific ip, ipsec is properly established.

I confirmed the connection failure is due to **%any** because saw the log in /var/log/syslog.
The log was as follows:

> unable to resolve %any, initiate aborted

The config file **ipsec.conf** was:

config setup
charondebug="ike 2, knl 2, cfg 2, net 2, esp 2, dmn 2, 100"

conn %default
ikelifetime=8h
lifetime=12h
keyingtries=%forever
authby=secret
keyexchange=ikev1

conn host_to_host
type=transport
authby=secret
ike=aes128-sha256-modp2048, aes256-sha256-modp2048
esp=aes128-sha256, aes256-sha256
left=x.x.x.x
leftsubnet=x.x.x.x/32
right=%any
rightsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
aggressive=no
auto=start
dpddelay=30s
dpdtimeout=120s
dpdaction=restart

Can anyone say why did this happen?
When i used auto=route, the system went down.

Answer (score 1):

> I used %any for right. Since then, I am not able to up my ipsec transport mode connection. But when i give specific ip, ipsec is properly established.

IPsec, just like TLS or SSH, needs active negotiation between hosts before the connection can go up.

`auto=start` means "actively initiate IKE exchange with the remote host", therefore it requires an actual single remote host address (IP or DNS) that it could talk to – it makes no sense to ask the program to "start negotiating IKE with %any". It's like trying to SSH to 255.255.255.255.

> When i used `auto=route`, the system went down.

It didn't go down; it's not responding because it is trying to negotiate IKE with you. `auto=route` doesn't just make the host accept incoming IKE, it also makes it trigger IKE on all outgoing traffic that matches the selectors – and because you used %any, of course it will apply equally to traffic between the two boxes *and* to traffic between the box and your SSH client.

In the end, you're asking for an impossible combination: you want the two hosts to use IPsec between each other, but you want the two hosts to *not* use IPsec against other systems such as your PC, and you provide them with *no way to distinguish* which is which.

You could use `auto=add` (the default mode that you've been using before) which makes the hosts act as passive IKE responders only (allowing them to receive IKE handshakes from %any without triggering IKE on outbound traffic), but at least *one* of the hosts needs to be configured with the other host's exact address so that it could know that it needs to initiate IKE when talking to that host but not when talking to various other hosts.

Alternatively, you could use `auto=route` with %any but then you must limit your selectors to specific protocols or TCP/UDP ports only; e.g. `%dynamic[gre]` or `%dynamic[tcp/23]`, so that it would not trap traffic that's not meant to be IPsec'd.

---

The ipsec.conf format in strongSwan has been deprecated several years ago. New configuration should be done through `/etc/swanctl`.